# AttributeError: 'T5Config' object has no attribute 'adapters'

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, summarization

How to solve this error? I've created the **.pkl** object of the **T5-base** model and tried to execute it but suddenly I got this error message. I wondered a bit, tried to google it but didn't get any reason why I got this error!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was thinking right!!!

**I did 2 experiments :**

1. install only `transformers` library :
   When I load the model, each layer of the model was without an adapter attribute!!
2. install only `adapter-Transformers` library :
   When I load the model, each layer of the model was with an adapter attribute!!

**Conclusion** : install `adapter-Transformers`